# Removing Textboxes

Tags: javascript

Im new to js kindly help me! im using functionality to add text boxes dynamically im done with that part now i want make a js function that removes text boxes on a click on remove button. any help ?

Comment: could you post the code done upto now.

Comment: This task is so easy, you are just lazy to read some tutorial and want other people to do your homework for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow JavaScript function to Remove elements.

```
function removeElement(divNum) {

  var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

  d.removeChild(olddiv);

}
```

If you have more information you can visit [here](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @devan, can you guide me what these olddiv and divNum will be in my code ?
myDiv is id of my Empty div that i know

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove a child with 
    document.getElementById(n).removeChild(thebox);
or you can do as on this thread [Remove <p class="classname"> in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720207/remove-p-class-classname-in-javascript)
 (not recommanded for your case)
Finally, you can use jquery (famous library) with the function $("#id_of_element").remove(); (best and easiest solution)